Ezra 2:11 - does the name Bebai (אָב) signify fatherly?
בְּנֵ֣י בֵבָ֔י שֵׁ֥שׁ מֵאֹ֖ות עֶשְׂרִ֥ים וּשְׁלֹשָֽׁה׃ ס
Gesenius' lexicon says that bāb signifies father in Pehlvi (p.111) https://archive.org/details/hebrewenglishlex00geserich/page/110/mode/2up. And my question is so what? (in a genuine and non-confrontational sense of so what)
This is an individual with three sons, but that doesn't mean his name means 'fatherly' even if it says fatherly.
Strongs says "Bebai - Probably of foreign origin" and Smith's Bible Dictionary and International Standard Bible Encyclopedia both have (fatherly) - - but are they all getting that from Gesenius' note?
Father in Hebrew is ab(אָב) but the aleph matters to the meaning, which makes me think Strongs and the dictionaries are probably needing to rely on Gesenius' Pehlvi/Pahlavi point.
Pahlavi is a language of (basically) Parthia and Scythia that (largely) uses Aramaic lettering. So it's not impossibly far away linguistically or geographically or typographically from the Israelites who are returning from exile in Babylon. But they're returning ~538BCE which is a couple of centuries before historians think Pahlavi comes into being. Of course the Parthians were speaking and writing something, and باب=bāb is a pretty simple/irreducible sound that presumably had a common ancestor, together with Hebrew's 'ab', whose echoes are still being felt in our word 'pappa'
So has Gesenius shared a factoid, which is potentially as trite as babies make b sounds and Bebai's name has bs in it, and the factoid has then been uncritically adopted by three modern texts? Or is there some tighter link - either back to Pahlavi, or directly between בֵבָ֔י and אָב - that's known to Semitists but which Gesenius hadn't space for?

The first Pahlavi dictionary https://archive.org/details/dli.csl.7740/page/n1/mode/2up apparently came into existence in 1877, so Gesenius must have been using something else.
It has khaneebaba=the door of a house, which might match Hitchcock's Bible Names Dictionary which has 'void' for Bebai, and Hebrew בָּבׇה=hole/hollow.
There is also ab=father/patron/benefactor https://archive.org/details/dli.csl.7740/page/n263/mode/2up

IMHO, the etymological explanation is a bit far-fetched: papa/dad are similar in structure with baba/bab, and likely come from among the first sounds that a child can pronounce. The choice of the specific consonant is likely determined by the phonological system of the parental language - as parents usually attribute more meaning to these utterings than the child itself.

Short Answer: There may be a linguistic basis for associating the name Bebai with “fatherly”.
Abarim Publications' Biblical Dictionary covers it well which I'll summarize:

Name origin: The derivation of the name Bebai is unclear.
Hebrew term: A potential source is the Hebrew word בבה (baba),
meaning “apple” or “pupil” of the eye.
Biblical occurrence: This feminine noun appears only once in the Bible, in Zechariah 2:8, (in the construction "the baba of the eye").
Etymology: The root of בבה (baba) is unclear.

Some, like Gesenius, connect it to the Hebrew verb נבב (nabab), “to hollow out,” (Job 11:12, Jeremiah 52:21)
suggesting בבה (baba) means “opening” of the eye.
Others relate it to infant sounds, possibly linked to the word
“baby,” interpreting בבה (baba) as “child” of the eye.


Name interpretation: The NOBSE Study Bible Name List interprets Bebai
as “Fatherly,” hinting at a connection with אב ('ab), the Hebrew word
for “father.”



The name Bebai: Summary
Meaning

Apple of My Eye
Fatherly, With The Desire Of The Lord

Etymology

From the noun בבה (baba), apple of the eye.
From (1) the prefix ב (be), in, and (2) the noun אב ('ab), father,    and possibly (3) יה (yah), the name of the Lord.



On fatherly:
Excerpted from: Abarim Publications' Biblical Dictionary:
אב

The noun אב ('ab) means father, but describes primarily a social
relationship rather than a biological one. That social fatherhood was
the defining quality of the community's alpha male, the one around
whom all economy revolved and from whom emanated all instructions by
which the 'sons' (בן, ben) operated. It's unclear where this word אב
('ab) comes from but the verb abu means to decide.


Alfred Jones (Dictionary of Old Testament Proper Names) believes the
name Bebai is a contraction of a larger term that starts out with the
particle ב (be), meaning in our by:

Excerpted from: Abarim Publications' Biblical Dictionary
ב

Prefix ב (be) means in, within or by means of.


Jones' proposed term further incorporates the assumed root of the word
אב ('ab), meaning father, which is אבה ('aba), which for this occasion
is said to be a verb and to mean to desire or long for (an
interpretation which is not shared with any of the other sources, and
is dubious at best). Finally Jones insists that the final letter י
(yod) is itself a truncation of יהוה (YHWH; Yahweh, the name of the
Lord). Hence Jones renders the name Bebai the meaning of With The
Desire Of The Lord.

From Jones' Dictionary of Old Testament Proper Names:

Smith's Bible Dictionary
Bebai
(fatherly)

"Sons of Bebai," 623 (Nehe 6:28) in number, returned from Babylon
with Zerubbabel, (2:11; Nehemiah 7:16) (B.C. 536), and at a later
period twenty-eight more under Zechariah, son of Bebai, returned
with Ezra. (Ezra 8:11) Four of this family had taken foreign wives.
(Ezra 10:28) The name occurs also among those who sealed the
covenant. (Nehemiah 10:15)
Father of Zechariah, who was the leader of the twenty-eight men of
his tribe mentioned above.


Pupil of the eye:
The Enduring Word Commentary suggests that Bebai means "pupil of the eye"

c. Parosh…Shephatiah…Arah: These names reflect the variety of
influences that came in and among the children of Israel during the
exile. Many of the names are connected to Biblical ideas, and others
have connections to their exilic culture.
i. “The practice of giving Babylonian or Persian names to Jews in
captivity (Esther 2:7; Daniel 1:7) is richly illustrated by the
archives of Murashu.” (Yamauchi)
ii. The names themselves give a personal flavor.
. ...
· Bani is a shortened form of Benaiah, meaning Yahweh has built.
· Bebai means pupil of the eye.
· Azgad means Gad is strong.
. ...


Void/Empty:
Hitchcock's Bible Names Dictionary
Bebai
void, empty

+1 for the research thank you. Re. "Pupil" that's the one I trust most so far. But it's not "pupil" as it's missing the specifier 'ayin' to make the idiom "gate of the eye". And it's not apple the fruit, this is a Mr Gates. For "with the desire of the Lord" Alfred Jones cites Sim. but doesn't say who Sim. is and I'm uneasy with them just dropping the Aleph. Re. "fatherly" Abarim Productions (or perhaps their LLM) either cite right author wrong book or wrong author wrong book. https://archive.org/details/jonesdictionaryo0000jone_m8w1/page/60/mode/2up only has "with the desire of the Lord"

@FelixLXX I also UV. I think that "Pupil" seems to fit the best. The Strong's does note that it is "probably of foreign origin". As for Jones, he does not directly translate Bebai as “fatherly”. Instead, he suggests that Bebai could be a contraction of a larger term that incorporates the Hebrew word for father, אב ('ab), and possibly יה (yah), the name of the Lord. Hence, Jones interprets the name Bebai as "With the desire of the Lord".
